# Accessing Site Collection Administration Recycle Bin through REST API for Sharepoint (Office365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, recycle-bin, onedrive-for-business

I'm looking for a way to access the Site Collection Administration Recycle Bin through REST API endpoints for Sharepoint.

Is this possible? The only information I found on the net is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246968%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

How do I use this to achieve my goal? Much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No. But you can use the new Management Activity API, it will give you PUSH events for such actions. Might wanna look into that.